# why my addition function for polynomial class not working?

Tags: java, oop, dynamic-arrays

i created my own dynamic array specifically for storing polynomials.
    here i am able to store my polynomials and is able to print them, after setting the coefficients but not able to perform add function. i have created the function. but it is not giving any output.

This is my dynamic Array.....

```
public class DynamArray {
    int []a=new int[2];

    void check(int index) {
        while (index+1>a.length) {
            int b[]=new int[2*a.length];
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
                b[i]=a[i];
            }
            a=b;
        }   
    }
    public void add(int degree,int coefficient) {
        check(degree);
        a[degree]=coefficient;
    }


}
```

and this is my polynomial class.

```
package classes_objects;

public class polynomial {
    DynamArray d1=new DynamArray();
    void setCoefficient(int degree,int coefficient) {
        d1.add(degree, coefficient);
    }
    void print() {
        for(int i=d1.a.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(d1.a[i]!=0) {
                if(i==0) {
                    System.out.print(d1.a[0]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(d1.a[i]+"x^"+i+" + ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void add(polynomial p1) {
        int maxlength=Math.max(d1.a.length, p1.d1.a.length);
        System.out.println(maxlength);
        d1.check(maxlength);
        for(int i=maxlength-1;i>=0;i--) {
            for(int j=p1.d1.a.length-1;i>=0;j--) {
                if(i==j){
                   d1.a[i]+=p1.d1.a[j];
            }}  
        }
    }
    public static polynomial add(polynomial p1,polynomial p2) {
        polynomial p=new polynomial();
        int maxlength=Math.max(p2.d1.a.length, p1.d1.a.length);
        p.d1.check(maxlength);
        for(int i=maxlength-1;i>=0;i--) {
            for(int j=p1.d1.a.length-1;i>=0;j--) {
                if(i==j) {
                    p.d1.a[i]=p2.d1.a[i]+p1.d1.a[j];
                }
            }   
        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

and this is my polynomialuse class to perform actions.

```
public class polynomialUse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        polynomial p1 = new polynomial();
        polynomial p2 = new polynomial();
        p1.setCoefficient(0, 5);
        p1.setCoefficient(2, 2);
        p1.setCoefficient(5, 5);
        p1.setCoefficient(9, 4);
        p2.setCoefficient(0, 3);
        p2.setCoefficient(3, 3);
        p2.setCoefficient(10, 100);
        p1.print();
        System.out.println();
        p2.print();
        p1.add(p2);
        p1.print();
        polynomial p=polynomial.add(p1,p2);
        p.print();
    }

}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Hello, in the class Polynomial you use  DynamArray d1=new DynamArray(). Is this the DynamicArray type you defined right before with a typo on the name?

Comment: sorry changed the class....

Comment: check the edit@SergioArrighi

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Hi @GARVITTYAGI. I created a working copy of your code and this is what I'm getting "4x^9 + 5x^5 + 2x^2 + 5
100x^10 + 3x^3 + 316". Since I'm not a math guy, could you explain to me what is the expected result please?